# Lower and Upper Case Regular Expression Patterns

Tags: regex

I am not that familiar with regular expressions.

I have the following regular expression `c-(move|store)-(rsp|rq)` to match patterns and it successfully matches the following strings:

```
c-move-rsp
c-store-rsp
c-move-rq
c-store-rq
```

I would like to make it such that is case insensitive. This is so that
it could match string

```
c-Move-rsp
c-moVe-rq
...
..
```

I am guessing that this should be pretty straight forward to do it for those of you who are experienced with regular expressions.

I have tried `c-/(move|store)/i-/(rsp|rq)/i` but this has not worked for me.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The `i` modifier takes care of that indeed... You can experiment with sites such as https://regex101.com/ which is indispensable for learning regex.... just type in stuff in the regex and modifier fields, and you'll see their description on the right as you add them.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
/c-(move|store)-(rsp|rq)/i
```

The flag applies to the entire regex.

In Python, Groovy, you would write:

```
(?i)c-(move|store)-(rsp|rq)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what language you are using, but most languages surround the regular expressions with a starting- and ending-character.  Typically these are forward-slashes so that your regex looks like this:

```
/I am a regex/
```

You can put [many different modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) after the closing slash. The important one for you is "i" to make it case insensitive so your regex will look like this:

```
/c-(move|store)-(rsp|rq)/i
```